# How to find the largest prime number where 2012! in the base of the number has at least that many trailing zeros.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Find the largest prime number $p$ such that when $2012!$ is written in base $p$, it has at least $p$ trailing zeroes.

I know that $2012!$ has $501$ trailing zeros. I don't know what to do next or how to use that information.

Comment: This should be equivalent to finding the largest prime $p$ such that $p^p$ divides $2012!$, should it not? That puts a lower bound to the answer at $43$, considering $43 \cdot (43 \cdot 2) \cdot (43 \cdot 3) \cdots (43 \cdot 43)$ divides $2012!$, so $43^{43}$ divides $2012!$ ($43$ is prime)

Answer (score 2):

The last $k$ digits of a number in base $p$ represent its value modulo $p^{k}$.  The last $p$ digits in base $p$ are all zero iff the number is divisible by $p^p$.  Now, for any prime $p$, the number of powers of $p$ that divide $N!$ is given by
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^3}\right\rfloor+\ldots
$$
So you want the largest prime $p$ such that
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^3}\right\rfloor+\ldots \ge p,
$$
with $N=2021$.  Looks like this will generally be $p \approx \sqrt{N}$, and here it's easy to check that $p=43$ is correct.

Comment: (+1) In fact it's always the largest prime $p \leq \sqrt{N}$.  Reason:  if $p \leq \sqrt{N}$, then the first term $\lfloor N/p \rfloor$ is already at least $p$; if $p > \sqrt{N}$, then the first term is less than $p$ and the remaining terms are $0$.